Windows 98 Msgsrv32 error during Setup
I'm trying to install Windows 98 SE onto a virtual machine (UTM) and for some reason, it keeps giving me a Msgsrv32 error. How do I fix this?
Here are the logs it gave me.

MSGSRV32 caused an invalid page fault in
module <unknown> at 0000:00006009.
Registers:
EAX=2056050d CS=204f EIP=00006009 EFLGS=00000202
EBX=00001c20 SS=2007 ESP=00006fce EBP=00007204
ECX=00000367 DS=05cf ESI=00021304 FS=05af
EDX=000000ce ES=1027 EDI=000279c1 GS=0000
Bytes at CS:EIP:
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Stack dump:
79c1f811 06c70001 7204031f 575111b3 220fb053
03c5bac3 3ce8d0ee 8aff1404 b204b0e0 cfb8efce
1c20bb05 d88ed98c 3605778a 047000a0 361f2408
8e7000a2



What VM config do you have (processor type etc.) and at what stage does it fail?

Are you sure Windows 98 is supposed to work on UTM? The UTM docs only mention Windows XP and later.

UTM is modern emulator. If it does not run Win98 it's not a problem of the only retro part of the question, Win98. UTM response to similar Win95 problem was that it's not their problem but upstream Quemu. Unlikely something you can fix, unless you are able to pull patches from upstream Qemu.

If the EIP dump is real (versus being a standin for an invalid page) it seems you're not going very far.  Either your load module is junk or the emulator can't handle it.

Get 86box and use it instead. I don't think UTM works well with Windows 98.

Evidently others have installed Windows 98 in UTM, but they didn’t mention hitting the same obstacle.
